# Why "Equals" method resolution with generics differs from explicit calls

Tags: c#, comparison, method-resolution-order

I have the following example:

```
namespace ComparisonExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var hello1 = new Hello();
            var hello2 = new Hello();

            // calls Hello.Equals
            var compareExplicitly = hello1.Equals(hello2);

            // calls Object.Equals
            var compareWithGenerics = ObjectsEqual<Hello>(hello1, hello2); 
        }

        private static bool ObjectsEqual<TValue>(TValue value1, TValue value2)
        {
            return value1.Equals(value2);
        }
    }

    class Hello : IEquatable<Hello>
    {
        public bool Equals(Hello other)
        {
            return true; // doesn't matter
        }
    }
}
```

The question is why in the second "Equals" call I'm redirected to Object.Equals instead of Hello.Equals even though I'm specifying the exact type in generic argument?

Comment: Because the signature of Equals is `bool Equals(Object other)`?  You're not even over-riding Equals (and missing the `override` keyword).

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but why not just `public override bool Equals(object other) { return Equals(other as Hello); }`?

Comment: Because I don't want to have troubles with GetHashCode

Comment: Troubles with GetHashCode? o_O

Comment: No constraints for TValue, therefore Equals from Object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you haven't told the generic method that your object implements `IEquatable<T>`:

Try now with:

```
private static bool ObjectsEqual<TValue>(TValue value1, TValue value2) 
               where TValue : IEquatable<TValue> // IMPORTANT!!!
{
    return value1.Equals(value2);
}
```

In your `ObjectsEqual` method you have access only to methods/properties/fields of `TValue` that are defined in the `object` class plus the methods that are defined in the interfaces/base classes defined in the constraints. No constraints => you have access only to `Equals(object)`, `GetHashCode()`, `GetType()`, (and if you have the constraint `class`: `operator==`, `operator!=`.) Of these two are virtual (`Equals(object)`, `GetHashCode()`), so you'll use the "correct" version, the third isn't normally overwritten (`GetType()`), so you'll probably use the "correct" version. Only the two operators `==`/`!=` are often overwritten and lo and behold! In your generic method you can't use the "correct" version of the two! :-)

Comment: Interesting, I'm still getting Object.Equals if I specify where TValue : IEquatable<Hello>. But your answer is correct, where TValue : IEquatable<TValue> does its job

Comment: @username I'll add that, in the .NET libraries, when they want to compare generic types, they do `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(T, T)`

Comment: `TValue: IEquatable<Hello>` means signature `bool Equals(Hello other)`, when in generic you need `bool Equals(TValue other)`.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov Got it, so I need `where TValue : Hello, IEquatable<Hello>` to make this particular example work.

Comment: `where TValue: IEquatable<TValue>` or `where TValue: Hello` is sufficient.

Comment: But the former variant is much better.

Answer (score 2):

**Addition from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)**:

***Unbounded Type Parameters.***
Type parameters that have no constraints, such as `T` in `public class SampleClass<T> { }`, are called *unbounded type parameters*.
Unbounded type parameters have the following rules:

- The `!=` and `==` operators cannot be used because there is no guarantee that the concrete type argument will support these operators.
- They can be converted to and from `System.Object` or explicitly converted to any interface type.
- You can compare to `null`. If an unbounded parameter is compared to `null`, the comparison will always return `false` if the type argument is a value type.

In this case `TValue` is converted to `System.Object` and `Equals` method called.